# Проблема в смене значений в sqlite3 (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite

[image: фрагмент таблицы sqlite]

Возникла проблема с таблицей
Не знаю, как заменить значение durability для объекта, если, есть объект с таким же id
Работаю на python'e

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: По нормальному всё же у каждой записи в таблице должно быть уникальное поле, либо уникальный набор полей и по нему индекс. Если такого в таблице нет, то нужно добавить в таблицу такой уникальный id, лишним никогда не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй выборку с rowid

```
Select rowid, * from tbl;
```

Изменяй данные по этому идентификатору

```
Update tbl(id) set (5) where rowid = 3;
```

Этот столбец не столбец, а номер строки в базе, по нему не построить индекс и может быть изменен при выгрузке загрузке данных. Зато подходит как временный идентификатор для строк без уникального столбца.